# Getting Blank PDF (without content ) using VF Email Template ( By default attaching PDF)

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

Original question:

Hi All

I have creaed approval process on custom object where i need to submit a PDF document for approval process. Once I attached the PDF file and submitted for Approval, am geeting email  with PDF, however without content, getting blank PDF.
Below is my code for VF email template. Please suggest....

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Document Submitted" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Compliance_Documents__c">
<apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015W0000000Dmru"
height="64" width="64"/>
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
        <img src="http://www.XXXX.com/ucmprdpub/groups/public/documents/logo/logo_png.png"/>
            <body>
            <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>

            <p>Attached is document related to Compliance Document "{!relatedTo.Compliance_Document_Name__c} ". </p>
            <p>Please Review the document and <B> Approve/Reject.</B> To approve or reject this item, click this link </p>
            <P>
                <apex:outputLink value="https://cs13.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.id}">
                    Approve / Reject
                </apex:outputLink>
                <Br/><Br/>or <Br/><Br/>
                <B> To Approve through email :</B> reply to this email with one of these words in the first line of the email message: APPROVE, APPROVED.
                <Br/><Br/>
                <B> To Reject :</B> Please click on the above link.
                <Br/><Br/>
                <B>For Comments: </B>
If replying via email, you can also add comments on the second line. Comments will be stored with the approval request in Salesforce CRM.
            </P>
            <br/> <br/>
           <b> Previous approval history </b>

        <c:ApprovalItem recordId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
         <br/>
          <br/>

            Kind Regards, <br/>
            Document Compliance Team

            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

    <messaging:attachment filename="{!relatedTo.name}" renderAs="PDF">
        <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.id}">
        </apex:repeat> 
    </messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Is that your complete code? Your attachment part, just repeats but does not have anything in it, so I would expect the PDF to be blank. Also, you cannot do a repeat on an id field, repeats work on collections.

Comment: Yes this is my complete code, however i am getting attachment through VF Email Temaplate, however content is missing.<messaging:attachment filename="{!relatedTo.name}" renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.id}">
    </apex:repeat> 
</messaging:attachment>

Comment: Your code has nothing in it other than a repeat tag. That would render a blank page.

Comment: I am not calling any API, directly attaching the document and sending the email to users.

Comment: You need to put what you want on the PDF inside the <messaging:attachment> tag.  Right now you have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<messaging:attachment filename="{!relatedTo.name}" renderAs="PDF">
        <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.id}">
        </apex:repeat> 
    </messaging:attachment>
```

In this bunch of code inside `<apex:repeat>` you need to use `<apex:outputField>` or `<apex:outputText>` and particular detail like if you want to display relatedTO.name in that PDF then use `<apex:outputField value={!cx.name}>` or any other field with the same way.

Comment: like <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.id}">
       <apex:outputField value={!cx.name}>
        </apex:repeat>
if you use like this then only you will get some value in PDF.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. for Eg: My technical writer will submit the document (PDF Document ) and hits the submit approval button on approval process, then here my first step will start and trigger out a email to the next approver to approve the document, and through email approver will receive PDF document which was uploaded by technical writer, however approver is receiving PDF document but empty content.

Comment: when is use    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.id}"> <apex:outputField value={!cx.name}> </apex:repeat>   getting error as :Error Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!cx.name}'. <apex:outputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: @ShakerKuncham you can directly use like <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo}"> <apex:outputField value={!cx.name}> </apex:repeat> but chech first . If you are getting values in that relatedTo then only you can use that inside the repeat so please make sure about it.

Comment: Hi Keyur , I am not calling any fields from the object, i will directly upload PDF document directly to related list called attachments, from there i will send the email to the customer however getting blank PDF document.